# Incrementing numbers in a list conditionally

Tags: python, list, loops

I am writing a program in Python and am trying to increment numbers in a list based on certain criteria. My code looks like this:

```
for i in list1:
     if i+.1 in list2:
         i+=.1
     elif i+.2 in list2:
         i+=.2
     else:
         i = i
```

However this is not adding anything to i, even if the condition is true. How can I do this? I know list comprehensions, but don't see how that could work in this case.

Comment: The current answer explains what to do, but it might not solve the problem because floating-point math is not accurate. For example, `0.2 + 0.1` is not exactly equal to `0.3`. You may have to add precision checks or rounding to your program.

Comment: Why don't you think it's adding anything to `i`? `i` is a copy of what's in the array, not a reference to the array element itself.

Comment: Why close as a duplicate? This question, as well as its answer, is much more generic and easier to understand than the duplicate, which is filled with json stuff, complex if sentences and method definitions; just because someone has asked a bad similar question doesn't mean every question should be closed. God I'm starting to hate stackoverflow, let's close good questions and leave awful ones, because the awful one was there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `enumerate` to get the indexes of the values and to update the list with the brackets like this:

```
for i, value in enumerate(list1):
     if value + .1 in list2:
         list1[i] += .1
     elif value + .2 in list2:
         list1[i] += .2
     else:
         list1[i] = value # useless btw
```

**Explanations**

In your code, you assign the values of `list1` to `i`, but the values are actually copied in `i` so when you change `i` it does not change `list1`.

To update `list1` you have to do `list1[index] += ...`. You can get the index using `enumerate`.

Moreover as @SvenMarnach said in the comments below, be careful with floating comparisons: for example `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` !

Comment: I dont really see the purpose of using enumerate.

Comment: Last line should be `list1[i] = v`. But why is this even necessary?

Comment: Which is important because you want to update the value _at that index_ in the list, not a copy of the value outside of the list.

Comment: This fixes one problem with the code.  Another problem is using exact comparison for floating-point numbers, which is bound to fail at some point.

Comment: Just as a fun alternative: `newlist = [(val+add if val+add in list2 else val) for val in list1 for add in [.1, .2]]`

Comment: @clemtoy so how do you compare floats?